# get selected navbar jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

im new in mobile dev, im working on a simpl mobile app.
im using jquery mobile.
how can i get the value of the  selected navbar?
my firt page is like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="first" id="first"  > 

         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="myheader">
         <div data-role="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">V</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">R</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"  class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">C</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
         <div data-role="content" id="de">
         <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="simpldial()" >Afficher</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

the function simpledial is this:

```
function simpledial() {

    $('div #body').simpledialog2({
            mode: 'blank',
            headerText: '' ,
            headerClose: false,
            blankContent : 
              "<ul data-role='listview'>" +
                    "<li><a href='#second'>go second page</a></li>" +

              "</ul>"+
                "<a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>"
          });
}
```

the second page :

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="second" id="second"  > 

         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="myheader">


     </div>

<div data-role="content" id="dd">


        <!-- Here i want to get the selected navbar in the first page -->
    </div>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you posted, all buttons are active because of the `ui-btn-active` class you added.

You should **only** use that class with the `ui-state-persist` with the nav you want active. Having that fixed, it would be as simple as:

```
$('a.ui-btn-active').text();
```

And you'll get the text of the current navbar. If you want to select it in **all** pages of your application you should bind that getter to the `pageBeforeCreate` event:

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).on('pagebeforecreate',function(event){
  var currentNav = $('a.ui-btn-active').text();
  // Do fancy things with it
});
```

Comment: yes you are right, can i fixe just one element with"ui-btn-active" and than i call $(".ui-btn-active").val() ??

Comment: You should use only one ui-btn-active at a given page.